How to clear Settings from QtCore?
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
import QtCore
Settings {
    id: settings
    Component.onCompleted: {
        settings.clear() // error
        settings.sync()
    }
    // GENERAL
    property string appName: "test"

Exception message:

Property 'clear' of object AppSettings_QMLTYPE_0 is not a function

However, Settings are built on top of QSettings, but sadly, you can't call C++ functions from inside QML. Is it possible to reset the Settings from QML?
